How to force refresh a VectorTileLayer in OpenLayers?
I have the need to force the refresh of VectorTileLayers, that is have OpenLayers generate new HTTP tile requests for the current map extent.
Without going into too much details, this need is related to feature edition. After edition the tiles containing this feature are cleared from both the client side cache storage (service worker) and from the server side Apache disk cache. All that remains then is for OpenLayers to generate the requests to fetch the tiles again, which will have pg_tileserv create a fresh set of tiles containing the edited geometry.
Anyway, calling refresh() on the VectorTileLayer source does nothing, even though it works fine with VectorLayer sources.
Things I have tried with no luck

source.refresh();
source.refresh({ force: true });
source.clear();
source.clear(true);
source.setURL('to something else') then back using source.setURL(original URL)
layer.setStyle(new Style()) then layer.setStyle(originalStyle)

The only thing that works is calling source.setUrl() using the same URL but with a datetime query parameter added to it. A common cache busting technique. Which is really not something I want since I want to control the cache of the tiles myself on the client side (using a service worker) and on the server side using Apache mod_disk_cache.
So how do I force OpenLayers to generate new HTTP requests to refresh the VectorTileLayer?
I'm using OpenLayers version 10.2.0
Edit: This is probably a hack but calling "source.sourceTiles_ = [];" before the "source.refresh();" seems to do the trick. Will wait and see if anyone knows a more proper or clean way to do this before setting this solution as the answer.

It seems you found the only trick/hack that works, unless Mike comes around and has some other trick up his sleeve.

source.refresh() no longer has any effect as the cache of rendered (canvas) tiles it used to clear is now maintained by the layer's renderer.  There is a separate cache of pbf tiles maintained by the source.
There is no API method to clear either cache, but both can be cleared and a refresh triggered using
  const source = layer.getSource();
  const cache = layer.getRenderer().getTileCache();
  cache.forEach((tile) => {
    source.removeSourceTiles(tile);
  });
  cache.clear();
  layer.changed();

Avoid accessing properties ending in an underscore as they are liable to be minified in some builds.

Indeed, I'd rather not use an internal property unless I have to. I just tested the approach you suggest and it's working, so I'll use that instead. Altough maybe I'll put that in a function for ease of use ;) Thanks.

source,refresh() is now working as expected in the dev version, triggering a clearance of both caches. https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/16328
